# PHP library to parse markdown and generate HTML/PDF

Tags: pdf, html, php, markdown, ebooks

I'm looking for a lightweight php library that can load a markdown file (it doesn't matter what flavor of markdown) and generate the corresponding HTML. I also need to be able to generate PDFs from the markdown, and ebook files would be awesome as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite happy with **[Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/)**, which I e.g. use for my website. It's completely open source (available [at Github](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/)), well documented, and a breeze to use. It supports "standard Markdown" and, via its *Extra* module, a bunch of additional features like tables, fenced code blocks, footnotes, and more.

Unfortunately, I cannot see it having PDF support built-in. So when deciding for it, you might need a second library for that. I've never needed that combination, but where I'm using PHP to create PDF documents, I'm using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for that – which again is free, open source, and produces pretty good results.

No recommendation towards eBooks currently – but that being a nice-to-have, I hope my answer is acceptable without it.

Comment: PS: For the eBook part, I recently found [PHPePub](https://github.com/Grandt/PHPePub). Have not tried it yet, but definitely seems to be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell rather than PHP but also standalone and with [PHP bindings](https://github.com/ryakad/pandoc-php) available and cross platform I would recommend [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/):

[image: From-To]

### Input formats:

docbook, haddock, html, json, latex, markdown, markdown_github,
  markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki,
  native, opml, org, rst, textile

### Output formats:

asciidoc, beamer, context, docbook, docx, dzslides, epub, epub3,
 fb2, html, html5, icml, json, latex, man, markdown,
 markdown_github, markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra,
 markdown_strict, mediawiki, native, odt, opendocument, opml,
 org, pdf*, plain, revealjs, rst, rtf, s5, slideous, slidy,
 texinfo, textile

Comment: i'm afraid i don't have access to install software on the server... otherwise, this would be perfect.